# Angularjs - How to expand the collapsed div on filter for the dynamic data coming from ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using angularjs,I have some divs coming from ng repeat and also I am using angularjs filter for search.All divs are collapsable except first div.Here everything is working but when I filter something related to collapsable div it should expand automatically.Can anyone please help me,Here is the code below https://plnkr.co/edit/QG98UGIPzZ2PYfBYhFEx?p=preview

### HTML

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>   
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### index.js

```
var app=angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
app.controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }

  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',

      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a']
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',

      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      list: ['item1c',
        '<b>item2c </b> blah ',
        'item3c'] 

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',

    }
  ];
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the 'isOpen' property of each group to 'true' when anyone searches something, which means checking the textbox value using ng-change attribute.

In your Html, add the ng-change attribute and assign it a function that you will define in js.

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="item.value" ng-change="onTextChange()">
```

Then in your js, you need to define the onTextChange function, which will check if the textbox value is not blank, it will expand each group -

```
$scope.onTextChange = function(item) {
   if($scope.item.value){
      $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
        a.isOpen = true;
      });
   }
   else{
      $scope.groups.forEach(a=>{
        a.isOpen = false;
      });
      $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
   }
};
```

Updated code - https://plnkr.co/edit/Qk9TdZ4oUWprA8Wi2Whw?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answer,its working fine but here once I remove the text again from textbox all the divs are remaining expanded,it should automatically collapsed like previous

Comment: Add an else statement to execute your code when textbox goes empty. I've updated the code, but that's a simple logic to put in.

If you want to retain the exact state of panels back (the state they were in before search), then you will need to save it in some scope variable and restore it back when textbox goes empty.

Comment: @carreankush Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help